# Is "murder" a noun or verb in "Mr Putin is guilty of conspiracy to murder"?

Tags: legalese, parts-of-speech

From **[The Telegraph's live feed](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/law-and-order/12111812/Alexander-Litvinenko-Inquiry-murdered-Russian-spy-live.html)** on the ruling in the *[Litvinenko case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Alexander_Litvinenko):*

> Emmerson says report findings mean Mr Putin is guilty of conspiracy to **murder** and should be held to account.

Is this word **murder** a verb, like **steal** in "a desire to steal"? I mean, rephrasable to "conspiracy to murder someone"?

Or is it a noun, but with no article used because it's part of a set expression in legalese? I mean, could we rephrase it as "conspiracy to **a** murder" or "conspiracy to commit **a** murder"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a verb. There's a simple test we can do, which is to see whether this word can take an Object. Verbs can take Objects, but nouns can't.

Sometimes nouns describe actions instead of *things*. These actions often have somebody who does the action and somebody or something that the action is done to. We normally show the person or thing that the action is done to using a preposition phrase headed by the preposition *of*. We can show the person or things doing the action with a preposition phrase headed by *by*. But we cannot try to give the noun an Object. This will be ungrammatical:

- the release **of** the prisoners
- the release **of** the prisoners **by** the government
- *the release the prisoners (ungrammatical)

So let's see if we can find a phrase which includes the person or people being murdered:

- The three men were convicted of conspiracy to murder people unknown.

Here we can see that the verb *murder* has a Direct Object, the noun phrase *people unknown*. Let's just check to see if maybe we could also use the noun *murder* here instead:

- *The three men were convicted of conspiracy to murder of people unknown. (ungrammatical)

No, this result is very bad indeed. The word *murder* is definitely a verb here. This also means that the word *to* is part of an infinitival construction. It is not the preposition *to* which we see in *go to the beach*.

For most native speakers *conspiracy to a murder* would not be grammatical. However the noun *conspiracy* can take other infinitival clauses as Complements:

- conspiracy to commit robbery
- conspiracy to steal
- conspiracy to injure

Comment: Thank you! I probably stumbled because in ordinary sentences the verb **murder** seems to always take a direct object. "I want to murder" sounds weird to me, unlike "*[I want to kill](https://youtu.be/m57gzA2JCcM?t=518)*".

Comment: @CopperKettle Yes and it also looks like the *to* might be the same kind of to as in *incitement to hatred*, for example. (Although it's not)

Answer (score 1):

I have a different opinion. The verb to [**murder**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/murder) is rarely used as an intransitive verb and almost always takes a direct object.

The big issue is whether **to** in "conspiracy to murder" is a **preposition** or **to in to-infinitive**. If you replace murder with **theft** which doesn't have a known usage as a verb, it becomes clearer.

If you Google "conspiracy to theft", you will get 83,700 hits. If you Google "conspiracy for theft", you get only 6,080 results.

Actual usage from [IRS.gov](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Examples-of-Identity-Theft-Investigations-Fiscal-Year-2015):

> On July 21, 2015, in Newark, New Jersey, Julio C. Concepcion, of
>   Passaic, was sentenced to 84 months in prison, three years of
>   supervised release and ordered to pay $5,643,695 in restitution.
>   Concepcion previously pleaded guilty to **conspiracy to theft** of
>   government funds...

The linked game site (based in the UK) has some interesting definitions, [Law & Order from Catreath.com](http://www.catreath.com/world/law)

> **Conspiracy to Theft**: Planning, aiding or colluding to the taking or
>   destruction of any item that does not lawfully belong to you without
>   permission, where the item is worth more than 5 gold pieces, or is
>   judged to be of particular significance. Theft encompasses the
>   poaching of game.

It also lists *Conspiracy to Assault of a Noble*, *Conspiracy to Murder*, *Conspiracy to Murder of a Noble* in addition to *Conspiracy of Theft*. As you can see all the words after the preposition *to* are nouns.

The reason you don't use the indefinite article *a* before *murder* is it is broadly used as a mass noun. You don't usually say one murder, two murders...,  but "two counts of murder", "three counts of murder", etc. are broadly used as in:

> He pleaded guilty to two (three) counts of murder.

Conspiracy **to a noun** is more idiomatic than conspiracy **for a noun** and sometimes the phrase could cause confusion if the preposition **to** is followed by a noun that could be used both as a noun and a verb such as *murder*.

Comment: I like the post, however, you won't find any examples (or actually you'll only find one example) on Google books. In the vernacular "conspiracy to theft"is shorthand for the longer mouthful "conspiracy to commit theft". You can compare those here [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conspiracy+to+theft%2Cconspiracy+to+commit+theft%2C+conspiracy+to+steal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconspiracy%20to%20commit%20theft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconspiracy%20to%20steal%3B%2Cc0). You'll see there's no result for "conspiracy to theft"

Comment: Here's the Googlebooks search for [*conspiracy to theft*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22conspiracy+to+theft%22) and here's the one for [*conspiracy to commit theft*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22conspiracy+to+theft%22#tbm=bks&q=%22conspiracy+to+commit+theft%22). Here's the one for [*conspiracy to steal*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22conspiracy+to+theft%22#tbm=bks&q=%22conspiracy+to+commit+theft%22) for comparison. So, I find that I like your post, which is well presented and well argued, but the hard evidence doesn't seem to weigh in its favour.

Comment: @Araucaria The word conspiracy is not broadly used for such a relatively petty thing like **theft**. If you replace *conspiracy* with **attempt**, you get 169,000 hits for "attempt to theft" and 406,000 results for "attempt to murder". Now, attempt is better suited with "theft" than "conspiracy". My question is "Is **murder** in **attempt to murder** a verb?" You get 31,800 hits for **attempt at murder** and 9,130 hits for **attempt for murder**.

Comment: Hmm, I can only find 1 result on Google books for [attempt to theft](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22conspiracy+to+theft%22#tbm=bks&q=%22attempt+to++theft%22) .... Even [attempt to thieve](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22conspiracy+to+theft%22#tbm=bks&q=%22attempt+to++thieve%22) is more common, it seems. I really liked your *rogue* post over on the dark side, btw :)

Comment: @Araucaria How about **conspiracy to treason** which has 11,100 hits and **conspiracy for treason**, 15,000 hits. **To treason** has 1,260 results in Google Books, too.

Comment: Have you tried them on Google books?

Comment: @Araucaria You didn't see my edited comment. Conspiracy to treason has 1,260 hits in Google books. Some books has it as their title.

Comment: I can only find two instances on Googlebooks, and they're both self-published... I don't think it's looking promising :(

Comment: But if you actually look in the results there's only two which actually have those words in! And in the one which has it in the title it's not clear whether it means *from conspiracy to treason* as in *armed robbery to murder*

Comment: @Araucaria Hmm... I am really not sure about this. Can you do a survey on this, too and let me know? We have to avoid extended discussion.

Comment: Oh, do you mean a survey of the teachers? If so, I can at lunchtime on Monday. The others are all off teaching right now. I've done a one man survey, i.e. asked my DoS. He agrees with me on this one ...

Comment: @Rathony You can **never, ever** trust those numbers that Google puts at the top of a "hit list" to bear any meaningful relationship to the number of actual hits Google can provide. For instance, if you track through the hits on "conspiracy to treason" you will find that there are only 202 actual hits, many of which are duplicates, and most of which refer to a single source, a book title.